# Need .bin file from MASM code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assembly, nasm, masm

I need the binary file of my assembly code.

With the NASM assembler, I can generate a .bin file by typing in the command "nasm -f bin -o mycode.bin mycode.asm", but my code is MASM.

I don't know a lot about MASM and Since there's no executable file it, how do achieve this by using Visual Studio?

Keep in mind, I don't want an .exe of my code, which is all I'm getting on VS.

Comment: MASM can make a COFF and you can maybe use Gnu Binutils objcopy to convert to bin?

Comment: @Ben That sounds interesting... Can you expand on that? I.e. how do I go about getting the COFF from VS?

Comment: You check the MASM command line options to see how to set format/architecture of output. Then run it like that. (probably put that command into some makefile, or at least .bat)

Comment: PECOFF is the default output format used by MASM, at least with the recent versions included with Visual Studio. However GNU binutils has bugs that make using PECOFF with any other format, including binary, a pain. The "standard" way to create binary files with MASM is to use the older OMF object file format (with the `/omf` option) and use the old Microsoft 16-bit segmented linker to create a .COM file. However the segmented linker isn't included with Visual Studio. Any other OMF linker  than can produce .COM files and runs under Windows would work as well.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks a lot for explaning! I'll definitely attempt this and I believe I may just have one of those linkers lying around somewhere... Appreciate all the help from everyone.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767340/how-to-create-com-files-using-masm-5-10